# How to place HTML input value as a String in Jquery object value?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

```
$("#btn_edit").click(function(){
    var token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');    
    var obj = {};
    obj.subject = $("input[name=subject]").val();
    obj.description = $("textarea[name=description]").val();

    $.ajax({
       type: "PUT", 
       url: "http://myurl", 
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "json",
       data: JSON.stringify(obj),
       success: function(jsonresponse) {
           $(document.body).append(JSON.parse(jsonresponse));
       },
       beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
       }
    });
});
```

but when the value is added manually it works well and even the input value is printed in the alert

```
alert("Text: " + $("input[name=subject]").val() + " " +  $("textarea[name=description]").val());

var obj = {};
obj.subject = "Hello";
obj.description = "Help please";
```

Comment: What happens when you try to use the first version?  Does it give an error or some other unexpected result?

Comment: gives unexpected result.

Comment: So $(document.body).append(JSON.parse(jsonresponse)); doesn't work?Or does it work but not the way you want and if so HOW do you want it to work?